# Combinations and permutations ( probability of 2 people being one in front of another in a queue)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A and B are queueing with 6 more people at a café. What is the probability that one will be in front of the other in the queue?

So basically I figured out there is 6! possibilities but don't know where to go with this.

Comment: Imagine B is late, and A is holding their place for them in the queue.

Comment: How many pairs of (distinct) spots are there in the queue? And how many of these pairs consist of two consecutive spots?...

Comment: My usual way of explaining this:  Rather than arranging A,B,C,D,E,F consider instead arranging X,C,D,E,F and then after that is done replace X with AB or with BA.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are queueing with six *more* people, there are a total of $2 + 6 = 8$ people.

Comment: Given the way the question is written, I would say that the answer is $1$ since one of them must be in front of the other.  However, I suppose that you mean one is directly in front of the other.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use combinations rather than permutations to more simply compute the required probability.

There are $7$ contiguous spots for a given pair in a queue of $8$,

Thus P(A and B next to each other) $= \Large\frac{7}{\binom82} = \frac14$

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are queueing with $6$ additional people, that will be $8$ total people resulting in $8!$ total arrangements. Let's save that for the denominator.

For the numerator, we want to count the cases where $A$ and $B$ are next to each other in line. If we know that $AB$ will be next to each other, let's group them together and count them as $1$ unit. I will call this the $AB$ unit. So now, there are $7$ distinct things we are arranging, which will give us $7!$ arrangements.

But this only accounts for $AB$, what about $BA$? We then count the arrangements within the groups themselves and we get $2!$. (intuitively think for every arrangement A is in front of B we can have the same exact arrangement with B in front of A)

In the end, we get $\frac{2\times7!}{8!}$ or $\frac14$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the brute force argument:(A in front of B) = y1 people A B y2 people =>
P(A infront of B) = $\frac{1}{8!} \sum_{y_1,y_2 \geq 0, y_1+y_2 = 6} {6 \choose y_1} y_1! y_2! =  \frac{1}{8!} (0! \times 6! + 6 \times 1! \times  5! + 15 \times 2! \times 4! + 20 \times 3! 3! + 15 \times 4! \times 2! + 6 \times 5! 1! + 6! 0!) = 0.125$

Now we have probability = P(A infront of B) + P(B infront of A) = 0.25.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are queueing with six more people, so there are a total of eight people.

Comment: But you have to choose only from 6 given AB (2 people)